# How to redirect user and pass a message to the destination page with Jersey and Dropwizard?

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, dropwizard

I have a POJO resource which defines some HTTP endpoints and returns Dropwizard Views. Some of these endpoints simply perform an action (eg. update the db) and then forward the user to another endpoint. For example, the user is at the location `GET /foo` and submits a form. This directs them to the endpoint `POST /foo/submit`, their submission is processed, and then forwards them to `GET /foo/done`. This prevents resubmission of the form if they refresh the page, for example. This forwarding is currently accomplished with Jersey's Response.seeOther() method (returning a Response instead of a View).

What I would like to be able to do is, when the handling method handles their submission, generate some sort of message (error message, warning, successful, etc) and pass that message to the page we forward to. For example, at `GET /foo/done`, I would like it to say at the top of the page, "Submission complete!" or "Submission failed because...".

I've done some searching around and a lot of people are suggesting to throw a WebApplicationException - except not all of my cases are errors. Sometimes I'd like to just show a confirmation of a successful action. But I can't figure out how to get the receiving method to receive a message. I've done it before in Python by having the handling method accept an optional dictionary but unfortunately I'm on Java 7 so I don't have the ability to give methods optional parameters with default values.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirects will simply send GET requests. GET request should not have any body. To send arbitrary data with GET requests, simply send it in the query string (of course there should be no confidential information here). For example

```
@Path("foo")
public class FooResource {

    @GET
    @Path("done")
    public String getDone(@QueryParam("message") String message) {
        return message;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("submit")
    public Response postData() {
        String message = UriComponent.encode(
                "You have perefected submitting!", 
                UriComponent.Type.QUERY_PARAM_SPACE_ENCODED);
        return Response.seeOther(URI.create("/api/foo/done?message=" + message)).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Not an ideal solution but it works. It'd be better if I could pass an object that's hidden from the user (eg. not in the url string). Is this not possible at all?

Comment: Not that I know of. To keep it cleaner, you can always send something like a number that has no meaning to the outside world, but gets mapped to something on the receiving end